# CIDR Binary reading

Tags: ip, cidr

HI you all im currently studying Network Address..

I wanna know the CIDR of this coz im a little confused on what will be the right CIDR...
well i know in ..
IP: 202.67.132.1
Sub:255.224.0.0

its CIDR is 202.67.132.1/10

but i get confused in the other question..

IP: 172.16.254.255
Sub: 255.255.253.0

the binary for that is..
11111111.1111111.11111101.00000000

so will it be 172.16.254.255/23? or /21? /o /24?

Im not sure if im gonna count the 1 after the 0 or I will stop counting when i encounter a 0?

tnx in advance..

Comment: 255.255.253.0 is not a valid net mask.

Answer (score 0):

seems like the example printed in out booklet has a typographical error :D...
sorry...

It is impossible to answer this...